# keyboards hide entering text

Tags: iphone

I am working on QuickDialog at [here](http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog)

However, my view can not scroll and the keyboard is hiding the entering text. What I am having so far is 
- (void)loadView {

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden       =   NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor   =   [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton                 =   NO;
NSLog(@"LOAD VIEW");

self.root                       =   [[QRootElement alloc] init] ;
self.root.controllerName        =   @"CreateAccountViewController";
self.root.grouped               =   YES;
self.root.title                 =   @"Registration";
[super loadView];

QSection    *section1               =   [[QSection alloc] init];

// Create title cell 
QEntryElement *cell1            =   [[QEntryElement alloc] init];
cell1.title                     =   @"Title: ";
cell1.key                       =   @"title";
cell1.placeholder               =   @"Mr/Mrs/Miss";
cell1.hiddenToolbar             =   YES;
cell1.autocapitalizationType    =   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
cell1.autocorrectionType        =   UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

// Create firstName cell 
QEntryElement *cell2            =   [[QEntryElement alloc] init];
cell2.title                     =   @"FirstName: ";
cell2.key                       =   @"firstName";
cell2.placeholder               =   @"Enter your first name";
cell2.hiddenToolbar             =   YES;
cell2.autocapitalizationType    =   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
cell2.autocorrectionType        =   UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;


// Create lastName cell 
QEntryElement *cell3            =   [[QEntryElement alloc] init];
cell3.title                     =   @"LastName: ";
cell3.key                       =   @"lastName";
cell3.placeholder               =   @"Enter your last name";
cell3.hiddenToolbar             =   YES;
cell3.autocapitalizationType    =   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
cell3.autocorrectionType        =   UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

// Create phone number cell 
QEntryElement *cell4          =   [[QEntryElement alloc] init];
cell4.title                   =   @"Phone: ";
cell4.key                     =   @"phoneNumber";
cell4.placeholder             =   @"Enter your phone number";
cell4.hiddenToolbar           =   YES;
cell4.autocapitalizationType  =   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
cell4.autocorrectionType      =   UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
.............................
.............................

[main addElement:cell1];
[main addElement:cell2];
[main addElement:cell3];
[main addElement:cell4];
[main addElement:cell5];
[main addElement:cell6];
[main addElement:cell7];

[self.root addSection:section];
```

After running it, i realized that the keyboard is hiding the context because I have a long list of input. Also, the view is not scrollable at all
There are an attached image at [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntzQS.png) that you can see my problem...
![enter image description here][3]

I went thru the sample code and the view is scrollable so that the keyboard is not going to hide any text at all. 
Does any body have any ideas about this issue, please help. All comments are welcomed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for this record, since this question was asked, this has been implemented in QuickDialog, so you don't have to worry about it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to resize the scroll view to [screen height] - [height of keyboard] (this is coming from a similar post that I saw somewhere).

You might want to try that.

Comment: Dude... Never post again. You gotta keep that rep!

Comment: Hahaha yes indeed. Screenshot the hell of out it =))

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways.

1. To change the view height when keyboard opens or closes.
2. To change the view origin when keyboard opens or closes.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this code in the two delegate methods of your textField will do what you want. Here is the textFieldDidBeginEditing:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect textFieldRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
CGFloat numerator =
midline - viewRect.origin.y
- MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat denominator =
(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
* viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

if (heightFraction < 0.0)
{
    heightFraction = 0.0;
}
else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
{
    heightFraction = 1.0;
}

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}
else
{
    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And here is the textFieldDidEndEditing:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
[self textFieldShouldReturn:textField];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

If you want it for the buttons you can just setup an IBAction with the above code.

Comment: I guess the code itself is pretty self-explanatory. Just tell me what you don't understand, and I'll tell you! :)